# Greatest Integer Function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

OK so it's been a while since I've done this math. I'm familiar with graphing greatest integer functions as this $[3x]$. I've bumped into this problem and I can't quite figure out how to graph it. 
$$f (x) = x [2x]$$
How do I go about the $x$ outside?

Comment: Note that it's somewhat like graphing pieces of lines of the form $y=mx$ on closed non-overlapping intervals except that the value of $m$ takes on different values on each interval since $m=\lfloor 2x\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a piecewise function, with infinitely many pieces.

Say $0 \leq 2x <1$

Then $[2x]=0$ and $x[2x]=x(0)$.

Say $ 1 \leq 2x < 2$

Then $[2x]=1$ and $x[2x]=x(1)=x$

You will end up with a set of functions:

$$0x,x,2x,3x,4x,5x,...$$

Each corresponding an interval of size $1/2$ and does not include the right end of the intreval.

That's if $x \geq 0$ otherwise it'll be like:

$$....,-2x,-1x,0x,x,2x,...$$

Same idea. With the same information about the intervals.

The cool thing is that $2(x)(x-1) \leq x[2x]  \leq 2x^2$ , so as you can imagine the graph may look like a degree $2$ polynomial made up of line segments containing open points.